# Aligning horizontal views which are part of a VStack

Tags: swiftui, alignment, vstack, hstack

I have been given the following design for a tabbar:

[image: 1]

I'm pretty close to replicating it, here is how my implementation looks:

[image]

Where I am struggling however is the finer detail of the alignment of the icons. So here is my code for the TabBarView:

```
struct TabBarView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TabBarViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack   {
            HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                tabOption(inactiveIcon: Image.Icons.Stores.notSelected, activeIcon: Image.Icons.Stores.selected, title: "Stores", tabNumber: 1, height: 20.8)
                Spacer()
                tabOption(inactiveIcon: Image.Icons.Menu.notSelected, activeIcon: Image.Icons.Menu.selected,title: "Menu", tabNumber: 2, height: 26)
                Spacer()
                tabOption(inactiveIcon: Image.Icons.Account.notSelected, activeIcon: Image.Icons.Account.selected,title: "Account", tabNumber: 3, height: 26)
                Spacer()
                tabOption(inactiveIcon: Image.Icons.Basket.notSelected, activeIcon: Image.Icons.Basket.selected,title: "Basket", tabNumber: 4, height: 23.11)
            }
            .frame(height: 39)
        }
        .frame(height: 64)
    }
    
    func tabOption(inactiveIcon: Image, activeIcon: Image, title: String, tabNumber: Int, height: CGFloat) -> some View {
        Button {
            viewModel.selectTab(tabNumber)
        } label: {
            VStack {
                    if viewModel.selectedTab == tabNumber {
                        activeIcon
                            .resizable()
                            .renderingMode(.template)
                            .foregroundColor(.snappyBlue)
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(height: height)

                    } else {
                        inactiveIcon
                            .resizable()
                            .renderingMode(.template)
                            .foregroundColor(.snappyBlue)
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(height: height)
                    }
                                                        
                    Text(title)
                        .font(.Caption1.semiBold())
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So each button or option is in a VStack, and I am then placing these buttons within an HStack. In fact, I have 2 HStacks, one embedded in the other (the outer one represents the entire tab bar area, the inner one contains the actual icons and has a set height to ensure that the labels align).

However, if you look closer at the design the icons are all slightly different heights. They are not aligned across the bottom, rather they are aligned vertically, i.e. the vertical centre of the stores icon is aligned with the vertical centre of the menu item. How can I go about aligning these as desired?

It feels right to have the buttons in separate VStacks, and the text needs to be aligned at the bottom, but it then seems difficult to align the images.

Here is how my solution looks in view hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: Not all of your icons are the same height. Make sure that they all have the same height. Also, take a look into the `.offset` modifier once you have them all the correct size for making sure that they are in the correct places. A sample implementation of the `.offset` modifier: `.offset(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.1, y: 0)`. Take a look at the [Apple Documentation for the `offset` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/offset(x:y:)).

Comment: One more thing - it looks like the Stores icon is slightly different in your implementation (not only because it is filled, but it's lines on the bottom left aren't the same). I suspect that's how the 1st image is able to align all of the icons.

Comment: You are probably better off making a UIKit version, you can modify the controller much more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the buttons in separate `VStack`s but have them align vertically, all you need to do is surround the icon by `Spacer`s. By default, if there are multiple spacers with no frame assignment being used in a view, the extra space will be split up equally among them (the same way that you're using them in the `HStack` among the `tabOption` views), pushing the label to the bottom and the icon to the center of the remaining space. By doing this, you should only need to wrap each `TabOption` in a single `HStack`, with the height of the stack specified.

First, consider switching from using integers to represent your tabs to an enum, which can more accurately model your tabs.

```
enum Tab {
    case stores
    case menu
    case account
    case basket

    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .stores: return "Stores"
        case .menu: return "Menu"
        case .account: return "Account"
        case .basket: return "Basket"
    }

    var activeIcon: Image {
        switch self {
        case .stores: return Image.Icons.Stores.selected
        case .menu: return Image.Icons.Menu.selected
        case .account: return Image.Icons.Account.selected
        case .basket: return Image.Icons.Basket.selected
    }

    var inactiveIcon: Image {
        switch self {
        case .stores: return Image.Icons.Stores.notSelected
        case .menu: return Image.Icons.Menu.notSelected
        case .account: return Image.Icons.Account.notSelected
        case .basket: return Image.Icons.Basket.notSelected
    }
}
```

If you use this enum, you could clean the `tabOption` func up quite a bit, perhaps by converting it to a reusable struct like so.

```
struct TabOption: View {

    var tab: Tab
    var isSelected: Bool
    var height: CGFloat
    var onSelect: (Tab) -> Void

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            onSelect(tab)
        } label: {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                // These spacers will be of equal height, pushing 
                // your view to the vertical center.
                Spacer()                 <-----
                isSelected ? tab.activeIcon : tab.inactiveIcon
                    .resizable()
                    .renderingMode(.template)
                    .foregroundColor(.snappyBlue)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(height: height) 
                Spacer()                 <----- 
                Text(tab.title)
                    .font(.Caption1.semiBold())
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you use this struct, you would create the view like so:

```
HStack {
    TabOption(tab: .store, isSelected: viewModel.selectedTab == .store, height: 20.8) {
        viewModel.selectTab($0)
    }
    Spacer()
    TabOption(tab: .menu, isSelected: viewModel.selectedTab == .store, height: 26) {
        viewModel.selectTab($0)
    }
    Spacer()
    TabOption(tab: .account, isSelected: viewModel.selectedTab == .store, height: 26) {
        viewModel.selectTab($0)
    }
    Spacer()
    TabOption(tab: .basket, isSelected: viewModel.selectedTab == .store, height: 23.11) {
        viewModel.selectTab($0)
    }
}
.frame(height: 64)
```

There are better ways to handle notifying the view model of tab selection than I've shown you here, but this would do the trick.

Comment: This implementation works great - needed to teak one or 2 things but overall exactly what I was looking for. Agree with your idea to change to an enum rather than using Int. I'm kind of retro-fitting this as a custom tabbar to an existing app which used Int to track the tabs, but I think it's worth the effort to change this as it's much more sustainable.